# how to print array values from one view controller to another view controller's array in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to display array objects from one view controller to another view controller's array.
In first view controller i have parsed the xml according to that i have 12 rows in that view controller means i have 4 record with 3 different values for u r reference plz see image

[image: in this image there are 12 rows according to 4 records now i m selecting the values from drop down list for any one team and it will set next value automatically to the other team so i pick these value in 2 diff array so count of these two array is 4 now i want to print these two array value on label in second view controller according to 2nd image i want the out put plz see this]

[image: Here u can see the values in percentage opposite of team name i want same out put]
but now problem is that i have 4 object in array and i have 12 rows in second view so how can i display the out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `numberOfRowsInSection` to return the correct number of rows. Say your array is named `listOfTeams`, then that method should use: `return [listOfTeams count];`.

If that's not an option, add those 4 objects in an array, and add another 8 `nil`'s with them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    [listOfTeams addObject:nil];
}
```

This is not recommended, fix your table methods instead.

Comment: Thanx for reply..following is may code for out put   if ([arr count]>0)
 {
  for (int j=0; j<=[arr count]-1; j++) 
  {
   if (indexPath.row%3==1)
   {
    if([HArray count]>indexPath.row)
    {
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.568 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1];//BrowmColor
    
    lbl_confidencePercentage.text=[HArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"HValue %@",lbl_confidencePercentage);
    }
   }

Comment: else if (indexPath.row%3==2)
   {
    if([RArray count]>indexPath.row)
    {
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.568 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1];//BrowmColor
    
    lbl_confidencePercentage.text=[RArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSLog(@"RValue %@",lbl_confidencePercentage);
    } 
   }
   else if (indexPath.row%3==0) 
   {
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
   }
    
  }
 }

Comment: Hear[arr count]is array for records i.e date and team name and HArray is collecting 4 object RArray also having 4 object now i want to print array on label on table view cell according to [arr count]and [arr count]is 12  plz provide me proper code

Comment: Ok your going the wrong way, all the way. There are two things wrong: 1. You don't understand what you are typing, and 2. You don't understand tables. Do this first: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-creating-simple-table-view.html Because your code has so many things wrong, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I understood that, you didn't understand me. You realise only the LAST item from the array is written down in the label? All the items before are overwritten. Also, why would you want to do `indexPath.row%3`??? Get rid of the `%x`'s, and use `numberOfRowsInSection` correctly (`return [arr count];`)

Comment: i have already used (return [arr count]) in numberOfRowsInSection now i've displayed the data from arr according to group of 3 fields, for ur reference u can see above images. now i want to display value from HArray and RArray in front of team name that's why i've used indexPath.row%3..

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of cells as per the number of objects.